# How to auto-populate a string into character wise in boxes?

Tags: asp.net, .net

how to auto populate a string into characters in small boxes, which are predefined in a form?

eg: in bank account forms, if we have an account number, say, `01134567`, how to auto-populate it into a document with the same predefined form which has individual cells for each of the number? like `[0][1][1][3]` ... (each sq. bracket symbolizes a cell)

Comment: You want this on client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programatically by creating a loop for each character in the string and create a dynamic textbox for it.

```
string BankAccount = "01134567";

//create a textbox for every number in the string
for (int i = 0; i < BankAccount.Length; i++)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "BankNr" + i;
    tb.Text = BankAccount.Substring(i, 1);
    tb.MaxLength = 1;
    tb.Width = 10;

    //add the textbox to the page
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

If you have prefedined textboxes and do not want to create them dynamically, you only have to make sure to set the value of `BankAccount.Substring(i, 1)` in the correct textbox.

Comment: thank you ... i'll come back if it's not working ... looks like it'll work

Comment: Just remember that dynamic controls have to be recreated every PostBack, so do not wrap it in `IsPostBack` check.

Answer (score 0):

You can create boxes (assuming textboxes) directly from the string using linq.

```
var accountNumber = "01134567";
var textBoxes = accountNumber.ToArray()
                  .Select((c, idx) => new TextBox() { Name = "TextBox " + idx, Text = c.ToString()})
                  .ToList();
```